# Kotlin: I want to update an array of letters while the array is out of the "if". How can I keep the update when the array update leaves "if"?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, if-statement, arraylist

The problem is, that the array will clear itself after leaving the "if" function, and I want to keep it saved, even in the while loop.

```
while (letters != correct) {

var missedl = arrayListOf("")

        if (word.contains(input)) {

            println("Missed letters: $missedl")

        } else {

            missedl.add(input)
            println("Missed letters: $missedl")

        }
}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
while (letters != correct) {

var missedl = arrayListOf("")
missedl.add(p)

      var p = if (word.contains(input)) {

            println("Missed letters: $missedl")

        } else {
            input
            println("Missed letters: $missedl")

        }
}
```

Comment: sorry but that code does not make any sense. You are mentioning a `while` loop that does not exist in the code. You are saying that the array clears itself after leaving the `if`, but you are not accessing or modifying anything in the array in the second piece, in the same place, the code has a `p =`, what is that supposed to be?

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I'll edit it.

Comment: ok, now it makes sense, you are declaring your array inside the loop. That means that no matter what you do to it during one iteration, it will just create a new empty one at the next iteration. Move the arrray out of the loop.

Comment: Yes it works right now. Had to put in .distinct() because the letter was showing twice. Thx a lot.